# If VM to Cloud storage API is connecting over external IP in same gcp region, will I get charge more than using internal IP or it will be same?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

according to this public doc - https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/access-apis-external-ip

it says it will stay within the Google network but what about the pricing. No clear explanation here.